# Boruta: 'max_depth' : depth = self.estimator.get_params()['max_depth']

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, knn, feature-selection

I tried to find the most important feachers , useing boruta feacher selector, it reach good result using random forest clasiffier but when I try to use KNN , as esimator I got the following error

```
` rf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1)
  feat_selector = BorutaPy(
    # verbose=2,
     estimator=rf,
     n_estimators='auto'

 )

 feat_selector.fit(X_train, y_train )
 y_pred = rf.predict(X_test)
 selected_features=feat_selector.support_
 selected_features=np.where(feat_selector.support_==True)

 data = pd.read_csv(r'E:\Daneshgah \Data_OverSampling\Ghplipour1401-08-24_XX.csv')
 columns_name=np.array(data.columns)[selected_features]`
```

I tried to find the most important feachers , useing boruta feacher selector, it reach good result using random forest clasiffier but when I try to use KNN , as esimator I got the following error

```
`depth = self.estimator.get_params()['max_depth']
KeyError: 'max_depth'`
```

Answer (score -1):

KNN is not suitable for Boruta as it does not provide the importance of the features. Boruta is normally working around tree-based models. Other estimators can be used as well, but provided that they return feature importances.

For your specific problem, if you use the classifier that does not have maximum depth parameter, do not define n_estimators as 'auto'